# Rewrite URL to hide ?get= in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, get

This is the structure of my website:

```
website.com/events/beachparty?date=1224
website.com/events/poolparty?date=0101
website.com/events/boatparty?date=1105
```

There are lots of different pages all of which I would like to use the get feature on.

I want to rewrite the URL using htaccess so that they can be loaded like this:

```
website.com/events/beachparty/1224
website.com/events/poolparty/0101
website.com/events/boatparty/1105
```

Is this possible without having to create a separate rule for each page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible without having to create a separate rule for each
>   page?

Yes, you can use a regex, i.e.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/page([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /events/page$1?date=$2 [L]
```

---

The above will rewrite:

```
www.yoursite.com/events/page99/123
```

to

```
www.yoursite.com/events/page99?date=123
```

---

**Notes:**

1. `([0-9]+)` will match 1 or more (`+`) digits
2. The last forward slash is optional `/?`
3. `$` means the end of the line (url)
4. `[L]` = Last, apache will stop processing further rules

---

**Update based on your comments:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /events/$1.php?date=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^events/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /events/$1.php [L]
```

---

`[0-9a-zA-Z]` - will match any digit or letter from `a` to `z` or `A` to `Z`, 1 or more times

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However there is one small problem. I used 'page1' etc as an example. The pages have different names without any numbers in. Would there be a solution to this? Thanks,

Comment: I have changed the question with a better example of what the page names are like. Thanks again

Comment: It gives me the error 

"The requested URL /events/boatparty/0101.php was not found on this server."

My htaccess now looks like this:

"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


RewriteRule ^events/page([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /events/page$1?date=$2 [L]"

Many thanks

Comment: Is `website.com/events/beachparty` or `website.com/events/beachparty.php` ?

Comment: Without the .php. I already have a rule to allow it to load without .php Thanks

Comment: Please remove that rule, this new rule will take care of that. I'll update

Comment: It's working! But my CSS isn't loading? Please advise. Many thanks!

Comment: @Jexon You may want to open another question, this one is getting long :)

Comment: Ok - I will make a new question regarding the CSS. But, is it possible to have this rule and also a rule to hide .php when the user isn't using a date in the url? e.g www.website.com/events/boatparty

Comment: Great thanks! I have marked it  ✓! Now onto the CSS, I will see if I can find anything about it before asking a question! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Quick update on the CSS. I changed the paths to absolute paths and it is now working fine! Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/beachparty/([0-9]+)/?$ /events/beachparty?date=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^events/poolparty/([0-9]+)/?$ /events/beachparty?date=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^events/boatparty/([0-9]+)/?$ /events/beachparty?date=$1 [L]
```

Comment: **"Is this possible without having to create a separate rule for each page?"**

Comment: yeah it is possible